# Preventing state change in android due to orientation change

Tags: android, orientation

I use an SQLiteDatabase in my application which I created manually and then using it in the android application. To navigate through it I am using a Cursor. I am showing the results from rows in edit texts.

When the orientation changes, irrespective of the row which was shown, the first row is shown in the edit Text. I know that android recreates the activity on orientation change and calls onCreate() method again.

But according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html), I shouldn't store a Cursor Object in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() since it uses a Context.

Here is the code for creating Cursor.

```
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
Cursor c=myDbHelper.getDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable",null);
```

Another recommended way is to handle the changes manually, but I do not want to do so since I want to take advantage of the default adjustment of UI.

How can I continue with the same row when the orientation changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simplest way is to add this in your manifest file (for the concerned activity) -

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

Comment: I have tried this. The application still restarts from the beginning on orientation change. Moreover in the docs, this method is asked to be used as last resort.

Comment: you do not need to implement onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() in this case.

Comment: yup, screenSize is for the ICS and Jellybean i suppose. Others work on the lower versions.